# Using VBA to check radiobutton in IE, weird behavior

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I have come across a problem that's been really keeping me stumped.

My problem is as follows:
I want to check a radiobutton in IE using VBA. Should be simple, right? I checked on this site for solutions to this and I tried applying them to my scenario. However, it seems I cannot even get the element...

This is the HTML source snippet:

```
        <table class="MainTable" width="962px">
        <tr>
            <td class="HistorySections" style="height: 29px; vertical-align: top;">
            <span id="lblReportType" class="Panel4" style="display:inline-block;height:15px;width:409px;"> Report Type</span>
              <table class="MainTable" width="413" style="height: 60px">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 22px">
                            <span style="display:inline-block;width:110px;"><input id="optRCV" type="radio" name="RptType" value="optRCV" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'optRCV\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="optRCV">Receivables</label></span>
```

From what I can gather, my radiobutton is called "optRCV".

I tried various way to check the radiobutton, based on what I learned here, but it always failed. With an Object not set error on the line working with the radiobutton. Therefore I tried a simple line to see what was wrong.

```
MsgBox IE.document.getElementById("optRCV").ID
```

From my limited understanding of VBA and IE, this should have shown the Radiobutton's ID, right? I tried something similar to make sure I was using it correctly

```
MsgBox IE.document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")(0).ID
```

This line shows a message box with the ID (well the ID is blank but it does not cause an error).

Is there any reason, why I cannot interact with the radiobutton using its ID? Interesting thing of note is that when I click on the top part of the webpage and use View source, it shows a different source code than when I click on the part of the webpage where the radiobutton is.

So my thinking is that I first need to tell IE to look in the correct part of the webpage but I have no idea how to do that.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you by chance post the URL of the website for us to have a look?

Answer (score 0):

```
MsgBox IE.document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")(0).ID
```

Your code returns a collection of elements from the table which includes the span, td, tr, etc. so you shouldn't be picking up the first element if you wanted to get the radiobutton

Your code should look like this:

```
IE.document.getElementById("optRCV").getAttribute("id")
```